# radio button not working at angular 5 while getting @Input from other component

Tags: angular5

1) passing input to product-edit component

`<app-product-edit [selectedproduct]="selectedproduct" *ngIf="switchwindow == 3"> </app-product-edit>`

2) Initialised object in product-edit component

```
@Input()selectedproduct ;
```

3) then i used radio button as below

```
           <div class="d-flex outlet-utils-form-product-availability">
              <input type="radio"  name="workingdays" [(ngModel)]="selectedproduct.working_days"  value="true"> 
           </div>
           <div class="d-flex outlet-utils-form-product-availability-span">                  
             <span>product is available</span>
           </div>
           <div class="d-flex outlet-utils-form-product-availability">
              <input type="radio" name="workingdays"  [(ngModel)]="selectedproduct.working_days" value="false"> 
           </div>
```

Note: workingdays is a boolean value;

please give your suggestions

Comment: What is you problem? Do you want the radio checked based on the boolean value? Then you have to bind the value to the boolean `[value]="selectedproduct.working_days"`

Comment: this is a edit form, here i want bind the value as well as update the value ,my issue is data is updating but radio button not checked at first time, i console that object in constructor (wont come),then i console it on ngonInit, I  got the response. but  radio butten not checked